# Combine modular with the blog in Grav

Tags: grav

I'm trying to achieve something in Grav, but I cannot wrap my head around the logic.

I have a blog in Grav, which works great. I put these pages below the blog and the different posts are displayed like I want to.

Now I want to add a module, a simple form, where users can leave their name and email address so they get a notification with a new post.

But I checked the docs, and it looks like you cannot combine these pages and modular pages or do I miss something here?

Or do you need to do this manually and is it not possible with the admin Grav plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a form follow the docs [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/forms). Make sure that the definition of the form is within the frontmatter of the blog page file, which is actually displayed. Within the template file just use:

```
{% include "forms/form.html.twig" with { form: forms('<the name of the form>') } %}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the answer